# How do I set a Notepad++ variable?

Tags: printing, notepad++

Printing code with Notepad++ is very handy because of the syntax-highlighting.
Unfortunately I'm experiencing a problem with printing.

Now at the left top of the page `$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)` is printed, which is, `D:\cppWorkspace\project1\display\GUI\main.cpp`
I don't want the whole path, to the project, to be printed. However it also should not only print the file name.
In this case it should be, `display\GUI\main.cpp`. (which are packages inside the project and the file itself)

I tried to edit or set a Notepad++ variable, but I couldn't find a way to do this.

Hopefully someone knows how this can be fixed.

Thanks in advance,
Dennis

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the variables are fixed, and cannot be "set" - at least as of the current version (6.3.1).  They are simple replacements, handled in the `expandNppEnvironmentStrs` method in `RunDlg.cpp`

You're welcome to suggest an idea on IdeaTorrent (see the hosted apps menu on the Sourceforge project), or vote a similar idea up if one exists.